# how to check for multiple classes, and apply effect to all of them in jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops

Here is my code within (document).ready

```
$('.checkfirst').click(function() {
    if ($(".textbox").is('.required')) {
        var x = $(this).offset().top - 200;
        $(this).focus();
        $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: x
        }, 500);
        divHint = '<div class="formHint">This is required!</div>';
        $(this).before(divHint);
        $(this).prev(".formHint").animate({
            marginLeft: "380px",
            opacity: "1"
        }, 200);

    } else {
        $(".agreement").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

`.checkfirst` is basically the submit button.

There are various fields with a class of `.textbox`, and some of them have a `.required` class as well. If the person edits the input field, `.required` is removed.

So when the user clicks `.checkfirst`, I want it to find the required fields, put and animate the `divHint` next to all of them, then scroll to the first input field that is required (giving it focus as well).

Right now I know my code just applies `divHint` to the submit button (`this`). I need to setup a loop somehow, and I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is jQuery's each() function. If you use it in combination with some kind of validation flag variable, this should be pretty simple. For example, you could put something like this inside the checkfirst click handler:

```
var validated = true;
$(".textbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("required")){
        validated = false;
        //do all the animations here
    }
});
if (validated)
    $(".agreement").fadeIn();
```